# What is a good weapon layout for Hyperion Vanguard?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I just got me a shiny Hyperion Vanguard and I want to put it to good use. To do that, I need a weapon loadout that isn't horrible (fragmentation bomb launchers, what a disaster!). Ideally I would like something that will let me destroy capital ships, but still let me destroy large numbers of fighters quickly. I am not averse to switching between weapon groups, but would prefer not to have to switch them for turrets or install different weapons every 10 minutes.

My priorities are, in order of importance:

1. Capital ship destruction
2. Fighter defense
3. Energy sustainability
4. Not breaking everything in a 10 kilometer radius and making everybody cheesed off at me.

Comment: http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=281249 - A nice thread about the topic. This one as well - http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=248679

Comment: If you are getting this ship through the teladi storyline, I'd recommend saving before turning in the 25m to see if you can get an overtuned version.  I've seen overtuned hypes with a top speed as high as ~240 (though that may take a lot of reloads).  Add that to the engine tuning crates scattered around the galaxy and you can get a top speed of over 300, which is sweeeeeet.

Comment: @spartacus I've got a 246(?) m/s one, it's **all good**. By the way, I've asked a question about those Pandora crates http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103174/where-are-the-pandora-engine-and-rudder-tuning-crates

Comment: nice, I think 246(3?) is either the fastest or 1 off from the fastest.

Comment: @spartacus 250 is the fastest (or was in TC, anyway) according to some guy's research of the game, but reports of them actually being generated by people are as elusive as that blasted UFO base in X3:R.

Comment: @kotekzot I've been there! Its real! They sell a cloaking device that doesn't do anything :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hyperion Vanguard is one of my favorite M6 (the other being the Springblossom).  Not only does it have a huge cargo bay (biggest for M6), it is the only M6 that has a docking bay and can fit a ton of different types of weapons on board.

Here are my typical loadouts for the Hype:

Front Guns (8):

- 6x Concussion Impulse Generators
- 2x Plasma Burst Generators

Front Turrets (2x2):

- 2x Energy Bolt Chainguns
- 2x Energy Bolt Chainguns

Back Turrets (2x3):

- 3x Particle Accelerator Cannons
- 3x Particle Accelerator Cannons

Missiles:

- Wraiths
- Wasps
- Mosquito Missiles (for Mosquito Missile Defense System)

Reasoning:

- CiGs are your all purpose guns, but having 8 is overkill since your energy banks can't keep up.  Even 6 will drain all your energy at some point, but its good against everything M3 and up.
- You can never have enough melty goodness.  PBGs are the best anti fighter weapon in existance.  Even 2 is enough to melt the face off of every m4-m5 you come across.  Best yet, you don't have to be terribly accurate against those fast and agile fighters since the PBG has a huge aoe.  Also, PBGs has the best energy/damage ratio in the game, they're even pretty good against capital ships.
- I put EBCs in my front turrets for the added firepower without draining my energy for CiGs.  The EBCs alone are usually enough to kill most M3s in a few salvos, and your huge cargo capacity means you can hoard lots of ammo without trouble.
- The only options you have for the back are PACs, IREs, and FBLs.  FBLs, as you noticed, suck terribly, so I put PACs back there for a decent punch against chasing targets.  They are also pretty decently ranged to pick off missiles.

Sometimes, I go with 4x CiG and 4x PBGs up front, which is still a killer combo.

As for missiles, the wraith missile is your primary anti capital ship weapon.  Yes CiGs can do the job given enough time, but wraiths are just so good at it (8x125K damage).  The only down side is they're hard to get since its a Terran weapon, so hoard whatever you can pick up during those big TerranxArgon battles.  Firestorm torpedos, tornado missiles, and typhoon missiles can also be used as a backup if you don't have enough Wraiths against capital ships.  The hornet missile deserves an honorable mention as its the best way to 1 shot a khaak cluster at range before it separates, they are also great for asteroid destruction.

Wasp missiles are my favorite anti fighter missile, they're also good distractions so the enemy ship won't be able to target down your firestorm torpedo.  Usually I fire the torpedo then spam a bunch of wasps and things typically blow up nicely after that.

Comment: and a note about PBGs, be VERY careful with friendly fire.  I consider the benefits outweigh the risk though, especially for hoards of m4-m5s.